# JQuery DataTables Turkish Character Sorting Issiue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a data which is some of them starting with turkish characters.And when I sorting them they are going last records. I tried to use [turkish-string](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/turkish-string.js) plugin but its gave an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
at HTMLTableCellElement. (jquery.dataTables.js:1197)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLTableElement. (jquery.dataTables.js:1194)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
at n.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15104)
at HTMLDocument. (jquery-datatable.js:25)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
```

You can find code in below:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "turkish-pre": function ( a ) {
        var special_letters = {
            "C": "Ca", "c": "ca", "Ç": "Cb", "ç": "cb",
            "G": "Ga", "g": "ga", "Ğ": "Gb", "ğ": "gb",
            "I": "Ia", "ı": "ia", "İ": "Ib", "i": "ib",
            "O": "Oa", "o": "oa", "Ö": "Ob", "ö": "ob",
            "S": "Sa", "s": "sa", "Ş": "Sb", "ş": "sb",
            "U": "Ua", "u": "ua", "Ü": "Ub", "ü": "ub"
            };
        for (var val in special_letters)
           a = a.split(val).join(special_letters[val]).toLowerCase();
        return a;
    },

    "turkish-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "turkish-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );

 $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    'aoColumns' : [
                    {'sType' : 'turkish'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: can you post your code please , and what is the order of sorting you need ? why don't use a simple sorting with turkish characters , what is the problem if they still last ? be more clear please

Comment: @MoxGeek I added the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the extended function before loading your datatable

```
// extended function for turkish characters---------------------------
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "turkish-pre": function (a) {
    var special_letters = {
      "C": "Ca", "c": "ca", "Ç": "Cb", "ç": "cb",
      "G": "Ga", "g": "ga", "Ğ": "Gb", "ğ": "gb",
      "I": "Ia", "ı": "ia", "İ": "Ib", "i": "ib",
      "O": "Oa", "o": "oa", "Ö": "Ob", "ö": "ob",
      "S": "Sa", "s": "sa", "Ş": "Sb", "ş": "sb",
      "U": "Ua", "u": "ua", "Ü": "Ub", "ü": "ub"
    };
    for (var val in special_letters)
      a = a.split(val).join(special_letters[val]).toLowerCase();
    return a;
  },

  "turkish-asc": function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },

  "turkish-desc": function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
  }
});

// your data table-----------------------------------------
var dataSet1 = [
  ['A ', 'A '],
  ['Ğ ', 'B'],
  ['Z', 'C'],
  ['Ç', 'B']

];
$('#datatable-table').dataTable({
  'aoColumns': [
    { 'sType': 'turkish' },
    { 'sType': 'string' }
  ],
  "destroy": true, //To delete previous DataTable instance
  "data": dataSet1, //Link the dataset
  "iDisplayLength": 10, //Number of dataitems in one page
  "bLengthChange": false, //Change this to 'true', to choose number of items per page
  "columns": [ // Table column names
    { "title": "Student Name" },
    { "title": "Student Grade" }
  ],
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7IiF8J1Cagzxc1YoEY7z?p=preview)

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code as I tried their [turkish-string](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/sorting/turkish-string.js) plugin which is working fine for me and I also attached the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7IiF8J1Cagzxc1YoEY7z?p=preview). Can you share your code/problem via fiddle?

Comment: I tried it again but still I'm getting error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
    {"name": "Isparta"},
    {"name": "İstanbul"},
    {"name": "Sivas"},
    {"name": "Şanlıurfa"},
    {"name": "Zonguldak"}
]
```

Try `localeCompare` to sort strings with Turkish characters.

```js
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```